# MongoDB. Как сделать выборку документов "и" "или" за один запрос?

Tags: php, mongodb

Допустим есть коллекция

```
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("588719a68996d3b21e8a1b8a"),
   "key1": "1a",
   "key2": "2a",
   "key3": "3a,
   "data": "1485248934"
}   
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("588719a68996d3b21e8a096d"),
   "key1": "1b",
   "key2": "2b",
   "key3": "3b,
   "data": "1485248000"
}   
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("588719a68996d3b21e8a4d57"),
   "key1": "1a",
   "key2": "2b",
   "key3": "3c",
   "data": "1485248555"
}
```

Так я выберу нужные документы за один запрос.

```
$key1="1a";
$key2="2b";
$cond=array("key"=> array('$in' => array($key1, $key2)));
$list = $collection->find($cond);
В выборку у меня попадут все три документа.
```

**Внимание вопрос!**
Как построить примерно такой же запрос, чтобы выбрать все документы у которых

$key1 = "1a" или "1b";  **и** $key3 = "3b" или "3с"; (т.е. в выборку попадут только второй и третий документы.)

**P.S.** ответ в формате PHP всячески приветствуется, но не обязателен.

Answer (score 1):

```
 db.getCollection('test').aggregate({
    '$match': {
            'key1': {
                $in:['1a','1b']
             },
             'key3': {
                 $in:['3b','3c']
             }
        }
});
```

Ну или

```
db.getCollection('test').find({  
            'key1': {
                $in:['1a','1b']
             },
             'key3': {
                 $in:['3b','3c']
             }
})
```